# Why did Erwin bother to stand at the wall and stare at Reiner instead of evacuating with his troops?

Tags: attack-on-titan

We all know that badass moment in *Attack on Titan* Season 3 Episode 14 when Erwin stares at the Armored Titan, but what's the tactical advantage he would gain by standing there instead of jumping down the wall to assist Levi and his troops? And please don't say because it's badass; I'm talking about the in-universe explanation.

It cannot be because of the high ground to look over the battlefield, as they have no phone. Is it to distract Reiner long enough until Eren transforms, or is there any reason besides that?